# What is the reason behind having a StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter

I have noticed that, we can use a `StatefulWidget`to build any part of the UI without worrying about the state.

What I am asking is simply, what are the reasons behind having a `StatelessWidget` in the first place, when we can build any UI class as a `StatefulWidget` whether we are going to provide it with a `State` or not?

Does using a `StatefulWidget` comes with an additional cost that makes creating a **stateless** UI easier/faster/better using a `StatelessWidget`?

When I read the docs, I can not exactly point out the difference between using `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` when describing stateless UI components. [It is even recommended to](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)

> Consider refactoring the stateless widget into a stateful widget so
>   that it can use some of the techniques described at StatefulWidget...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your widget manages state, you should use a `StatefulWidget` with an associated `State` object to store the state.

If your widget doesn't manage any state, and its build method only depends on its constructor arguments (or `Inherited` widgets such as `Theme`), it's better to use a `StatelessWidget`. `StatelessWidget` requires defining fewer classes and invoking fewer methods, so it should be faster and more maintainable than an equivalent `StatefulWidget` that doesn't cache anything in its state.

If you follow the [*Push the state to the leaves*](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) performance optimization, you will be changing a `StatefulWidget` to a `StatelessWidget` and factoring out the stateful parts into a simpler `StatefulWidget` (which may take a `child` argument and cache it). This pattern adds more classes but has the benefit of reducing the amount of work necessary when the state changes.